# Adjacency matrix of a graph in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, adjacency-matrix

Is it possible to get the adjacency matrix of a graph in Neo4j?
Or do I need to build it myself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j is linking nodes directly, so there is no global concept of data, everything is local. You would need to touch at least all relationships to build that matrix I think, then keep it updated be maybe hooking into the transaction events for mutating operations, [see the docs and Java API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/transactions-events.html)